# Term for parking note left by driver in advance

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In Russia it is common to leave a note with your name and phone number in a car visible to outsiders, when you park for a short time in a place you are not familiar with or when you have to park in front of someone else car (due to lack of space) thus preventing them to leave, so that owner of blocked car can call you.

Is there a word or a phrase for this note in English?

I found "parking note", however it seems to refer mostly to notes left by others to the offending driver.

Comment: Probably just 'a note'. This isn't practice I've heard of in England so we might not have a specific word.

Comment: It's more usual in UK to see a **notice** such as "Electrician working in XXX".

Comment: This is actually a fairly common (if technically not legal) practice in certain locations in NYC; to the best of my knowledge, there is no specific term for such a note/notice.